# Some Sort Of Border Is Appearing When I Use A Table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a web page and i have a 3 column 1 row table set up (Bottom Of The Page). This is illustrated in the following figure.[image: figure]

As you can see in that figure, some border is appearing at the start of td tag (Marked By Black Circles). I've made the border 0 and still there is no effect. Why is happening and how should i resolve it?

I've Provided The Code Below..

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper col3">

      <div id="intro">

            <div class="fl_left">

                  <div class="UpperSlideShow">

                  </div>
                  <div class="LowerFlyUps">
                        <table class="HoverTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-left:2px;">
                        <tr>
                        <td>

                              <div class="box" id="box">
                                    <div class="inner">
                                          <h4>Header One</h4>        
                                          <p>Content One, Team Pwn helped us identify the root cause of our problems and delivered effective solutions to tackle them.</p>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                              <div class="box" id="box1">
                                    <div class="inner">
                                          <h4>Header Two</h4>        
                                          <p>Content One, Team Pwn helped us identify the root cause of our problems and delivered effective solutions to tackle them.</p>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                              <div class="box" id="box2">
                                    <div class="inner">
                                          <h4>Header Three</h4>        
                                          <p>Content One, Team Pwn helped us identify the root cause of our problems and delivered effective solutions to tackle them.</p>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>

                  </div>

            </div>

            <div class="fl_right"><img src="images/demo/380x300.gif" alt="" /></div>
            <br class="clear" />
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
table.HoverTable
{
    border: 0px;
}


table.HoverTable tr
{
    border: 0px;
}


table.HoverTable tr rd
{
    border: 0px;
}
.box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 175px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 12px Tahoma,sans-serif;
    background-color: #284062;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.box h4 {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    font: 18px Tahoma,sans-serif;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin: 10px;
}
.box p {
    margin: 0 10px;            
}
#intro
{
    padding:30px 0 5px 0;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

#intro .fl_left
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:575px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#2684B7;
}

#intro .fl_left h3
{
    font-size: 24px;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:2em;
}

#intro .fl_left p
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:1.6em;
}

#intro .fl_left p.readmore
{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:right;
    line-height:normal;
}

#intro .fl_left p.readmore a
{
    padding:8px 15px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#1C5E82;
}

#intro .fl_right{float:right;}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".box").hover(function ()
    {
        $(this).animate({height: 200});
    }, function () 
    {
        $(this).animate({height: 40});
    }
    );

});
```

Comment: If it is only 3 columns and 1 row, why would you not just use a ul with three floated li's? its half the amount of markup and very little css.

Comment: Mr Christian, This Application says i cant post anything for 7 hours. And i cant paste my code in this comment field

Comment: I've edited my post and i've provided my code. Please Help Me

Comment: I have no idea as to how to do it using li's. Can u help me with some code?

Comment: You're not showing the relevant CSS. What you have posted doesn't look like anything you have in the picture: http://jsfiddle.net/zaxH2/

Comment: I copied your code into this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DvtvV/ However, your problem is not reproduced.  Please update the fiddle with your code until your problem appears?

Comment: I've not given the css code for divs. Hold on a minute. I'll give u the entire cod

Comment: It still does not look like your screenshot: http://jsfiddle.net/DvtvV/1/

Comment: Hold On i'll post the entire website code on jsfiddle and give a link

Comment: Still no issue, but you will want to add a stop animate on those boxes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abilash_s_90/SdDeH/1/ Here is the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is causing it, the border-left and right. http://jsfiddle.net/SdDeH/4/

```
    table tbody td {
vertical-align: top;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

change to

```
table tbody td {
    vertical-align: top;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to duplicate your issue. But you could try adding border-collapse:collapse; to the table.

```
table.HoverTable
{
  border: 0px;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: i've given the replica of my code in jsfiddle.. Please take a look